# What does searching for a title backtick do?

Tags: support, search, backtick

I've been doing some editing on Super User, and I got a hunch that a good way to find questions in need of improvement would be to search for titles containing backticks. So I punched **title:`** into the search box, and got [this](https://superuser.com/search?q=title%3A%60).

None of the titles on the first or second pages of those results actually contains a backtick. However, the search produces only 1917 results. If it had somehow matched all questions, "5000+" would be displayed.

What did my attempt to find backticks actually search for? (I know this isn't directly a useful question, but hopefully the answer will help people be better searchers in the future.) I wouldn't mind finding out how to actually search for a backtick, either, if someone knows a way.

Comment: You get the same result just searching for [title:](http://superuser.com/search?q=title:), so I don't think the backtick has anything to do with it

Comment: Yeah, I think all sorts of non-alphanumeric characters are automatically discarded either upfront, or by Lucene. I suspect that this *could* be related to the entry count for a given Lucene index segment, but that's just a guess (especially since the number varies depending on the tab you select). On sites with lower total question counts, like Gaming, you actually will get [all questions returned](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A).